# .NET Search Connector without web (Windows Search)

Tags: c#, .net, search-engine

I want to provide a custom Search Connector for Windows Search without accessing a php or aspx website. Is this possible? I don't find anything.

regards Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the windows 7 version [Windows Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx] .There is an add in for XP and 2003 called Windows Search Service that would also give you an API.

Hope that is what youwere looking for,

Dan

Comment: hmm its much to read. example: I'm a DMS and want to provide documents to the user not only by my prog. The user should search my dms via windows search